# Where would be the most appropriate directory to put my own Emacs-lisp files in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, configuration-files

I want to create an Emacs-lisp file to store my org-mode configuration. This file will be loaded by `dotspacemacs/user-config`. My question is where would it be the standard directory (if any) where I whould store this file? I was considering `.emacs.d/private/local`, but I noticed it does not exists in `load-path`, so I guessed it is not intended for this kind of use. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to do, essentially.

If you have lots of extra functionality to add, then have a look at creating your own private layer. There is a [tutorial here](http://thume.ca/howto/2015/03/07/configuring-spacemacs-a-tutorial/), and on the spacemacs website, [here](http://spacemacs.org/doc/LAYERS.html).

If you plan to have small config files under source control, then having them within your `.emacs.d` is not a great idea because `.emacs.d` is already the spacemacs repository, and you wouldn't want to mess up the spacemacs organization with random files.

As an example, I have a `~/Elisp` directory where I keep my configuration files. This way I can have a repo with my personal config and have only a single directory that I have to add to the load path. When I grab some config files from other people, or repositories, I usually keep them in their own git repo (from where I cloned them), and add *symlinks* to my `~/Elisp` dir.

Small snippets of code go directly into the .spacemacs file, obviously.

(Looking forward to what other people suggest, too!)

Comment: So, there is no pre-defined directory for that. It is up to me to create one as I see fit, correct?

Comment: Pretty much. How to organize files is an open question. Everyone comes up with their own stuff, I guess...